# onclick=GA code gives server error 500

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics, onclick

I am trying to edit the google analytics onclick track code for one of my buttons. 
Current code is:

```
<a href="contact.php" onclick="”_gaq.push([‘_trackEvent’," ‘contact’,="" ‘click’,="" ‘outsouring="" werfleider’]);="" style="background-color:#ed1f24; color:#FFFFFF; padding: 20px 25px; font-family: PT Sans, sans-serif; font-weight: 700; font-size:18px;"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> 
                                Neem vandaag nog contact op met ons</a>
```

I am replacing the onclick="..." code with following code:

```
onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'link', 'Contact aanvraag');"
```

But as soon as I save the .php file and upload it to the ftp server, the page gives either an empty page (just white space, `<body>` tag is empty) or a server error 500.

Tried some different things now but I've got no clue why this is.

Comment: Which version of Analytics tracking are you using now? I assume you've upgraded to analytics.js?

Comment: your first code is using classic analytics (ga.js) your second is universal (analytics.js) which one have you included

Comment: analytics.js I suppose, got this code in the header http://prntscr.com/a3ye9f

Comment: A server error is produced by the server. GA is clientside code. So the error is produced by your page, not by the GA code.  I assume your link is within an PHP page (and your server is not configured to display PHP errors) that has an error.

Comment: Sometimes the page says 'error 500', other times I just get an empty page, <body> content is empthy then.

Comment: Your host should provide an error log for your server, look what is says in there when you call the page.

Answer (score 0):

Page gave an error because the < a > tag was inside

```
echo '
```

replaced the onclick code with:

```
onclick="ga(\'send\', \'event\', \'link\', \'Contact aanvraag\');"
```

and now the page displays like it should.

Comment: You had unusual quote characters in the original source. Was the php file edited with MS-Word or something?